# java-regex split string after 80 char. if middle of string split to closest space before

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a long string and I'd like to split my string to into 80 characters but if when I split the string it's the middle of a word then I take the closest previous space.

Below what I got :

```java
String myStr = "very long string supposed to exceed eighty characters because some addresses are very long but they have space so should not be an issue to split them"
String[] splitString = myStr.split("[\\s\\S]{1,80}(?!\\S)");

log.info("split string : {}", splitString); => // return {}
  
//Expected result : 
splitString[0] => "very long string supposed to exceed eighty characters because some addresses are"

splitString[1] => " very long but they have space so should not be an issue to split them"
```

Can someone tells me what am I missing please ?

I did test my regex on https://regex101.com/ it's split my string as I wish. I know this website test the regex in JS but i guessed regex are quite similar in every languages.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Read the String.split() javadoc. What happens to the part of the string which matches the regex?

Comment: @tgdavies sorry i don't get your point.. I read the java doc but they doesn't seems to give a lot more information.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: `String.split()` discards the separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be hard to articulate a regex pattern which is smart enough to split on whitespace only up to 80 characters at a time.  However, if we use a formal regex pattern matcher, it is fairly straightforward:

```
String myStr = "very long string supposed to exceed eighty characters because some addresses are very long but they have space so should not be an issue to split them";
String pattern = ".{1,80}(?!\\S)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(myStr);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0).trim() + " (length: " + m.group(0).trim().length() + ")");
}
```

This prints:

```
very long string supposed to exceed eighty characters because some addresses are (length: 80)
very long but they have space so should not be an issue to split them (length: 69)
```